# Typedef struct and passing to functions

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to declare a typedef struct array and then pass it to a function but i'm getting errors because i'm not exactly certain the proper syntax, help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_COURSES 50

typedef struct courses      //creating struct for course info
{
    int Course_Count;
    int Course_ID;
    char Course_Name[40];
}course;    

void Add_Course(course , int *);

int main()
{
    course cors[MAX_COURSES];
    int cors_count = 0;

    Add_Course(cors, &cors_count);
    return 0;
}

void Add_Course(course cors, int *cors_count)
{
    printf("Enter a Course ID: ");  //prompting for info
    scanf("%d%*c", cors.Course_ID);
    printf("Enter the name of the Course: ");
    scanf("%s%*c", cors.Course_Name);

    cors_count++;   //adding to count

    printf("%p\n", cors_count);
    return;
}
```

The errors i'm getting are:

> error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘Add_Course’
>
> test2.c:28:6: note: expected ‘course’ but argument is of type ‘struct
>   course *’
>
> test2.c: In function ‘Add_Course’:
>
> test2.c:81:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’,
>   but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: C is a bit odd when it comes to array passing. You must pass arrays by reference. As was already mentioned, your function signature should be `Add_Course(course* cors, int* cors_count)`.

However, when accessing *cors_count, you need to dereference it. To increment cors_count, you need to do `*cors_count++`. Without dereferencing it, you're incrementing the pointer, not the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array to a function expecting an instance of `struct course`, try like this

```
Add_Course(cors[cors_count], &cors_count);
```

But then it will only be modified in `Add_Course` so you need

```
void Add_Course(course *cors, int *cors_count)
{
    printf("Enter a Course ID: ");
    /* this was wrong, pass the address of `Course_ID' */
    scanf("%d%*c", &cors->Course_ID);
    /* Also, check the return value from `scanf' */
    printf("Enter the name of the Course: ");
    scanf("%s%*c", cors->Course_Name);

    /* You need to dereference the pointer here */
    (*cors_count)++; /* it was only incrementing the pointer */

    return;
}
```

And now you can

```
for (int index = 0 ; index < MAX_COURSES ; ++index)
    Add_Course(&cors[index], &cors_count);
```

although `cors_count` will be equal to `MAX_COURSES - 1` in this case, it migh be useful after all.

Comment: Making the changes you suggested it tells me:
 error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘Add_Course’
 note: expected ‘struct course *’ but argument is of type ‘course’

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you didn't do the second part... `Add_Course(&cors[index], &cors_count);`

Answer (score 0):

In your `Add_Course()` function, the first argument is of type `course` but what you're passing is an array of type `course` which are not the same. You need to have a pointer to `course` as the first argument if you want to pass an array.

Next, `scanf("%d%*c", cors.Course_ID);` is also wrong, `scanf()` expects the argument to the format specifier as a pointer to the variable. You need to provide the address of the variable. Also, `printf("%p\n", cors_count);` should obviously be `printf("%d\n", *cors_count);`.

That said, `cors_count++;` is not probably what you wanted to have there. You want to increment the *value*, not the pointer itself.